# Create instance of new class in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I am new to Android programming but have a little bit of experience with Java. However, I am creating an Android application and when a user clicks a button I want a different class to instantiated...
This is my `MainActivity.java`

```
private void setButtonClickListener() {
    Button budgetPeriodButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.budgetPeriodButton);
    Button incomingsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.incomingsButton);
    Button outgoingsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.outgoingsButton);
    Button resultsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.resultsButton);
    budgetPeriodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BudgetPeriod bp = new BudgetPeriod();
            bp.changeUI();
          }
```

And this is the BudgetPeriod class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BudgetPeriod extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_budget);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        changeUI();
    }

    public void changeUI() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.budget_icon);
        Drawable newBudgetImage;
        newBudgetImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.budget_period);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(newBudgetImage);
    }
}
```

If the user clicks on the button, then an error message on the emulator says "Unfortunatley, this app has had to close"

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Activities aren't instantiated using constructors in Android. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Use Intent to start new activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the activity like this.

```
budgetPeriodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BudgetPeriod.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and make sure you declared the activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity name=".BudgetPeriod" android:name="Budget" />
```

Answer (score 2):

First of All, **you can not create an instance of Activity** like this, and calling method of it. Like simple Java Class. Because Android Activity has its own life cycles of calling methods.

You have to start Activity **BudgetPeriod** Using Intent in Button's `onClick()`.

Change your method like,

```
budgetPeriodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BudgetPeriod.class);
          startActivity(intent)
}
```

And register following **BudgetPeriod** Activity in **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Comment: One more thing remove second extra `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` from `onCreate()` of  `BudgetPeriod` Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Activity in android dosen't start by creating instance like this:

you need to use Intents to start activity like below

```
budgetPeriodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BudgetPeriod.class);
          startActivity(intent);

   }
```

and you need to register that activity in manifest.xml file like:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".BudgetPeriod"
    />
```

you can make yourself clear about intents by Following links:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html